# Firebase functions not compiling code. It's throwing status code of 246 when failing to compile

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My firebase functions was running fine till last night, but it has stopped working now.
When I run my functions I get this error on my Google cloud platform log -

`"Step #5 - "exporter": [31;1mERROR: [0mfailed to export: failed to write image to the following tags: [us.gcr.io/tookforms/gcf/us-central1/77926137-2972-4613-947e-c66d12cfd46f:calc_version-59: GET https://storage.googleapis.com/us.artifacts.tookforms.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:b18e538d0dbca11a254142f571dfce8058959925b5e8c2c25679211b8b1bf0c6?access_token=REDACTED: unexpected status code 404 Not Found: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: us.artifacts.tookforms.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:b18e538d0dbca11a254142f571dfce8058959925b5e8c2c25679211b8b1bf0c6</Details></Error>]" insertId: "3f132e37-fa6b-4f0a-8dc4-1244dca5a7a5-228"`

It's saying that it's trying to upload some image to somewhere on google cloud platform. But I don't have anything to do with any image in my function. I don't even understand exactly what the "image" means over here.

This is the second error I am getting just below the first error -

`ERROR: build step 5 "us.gcr.io/fn-img/buildpacks/nodejs12/builder:nodejs12_20210310_12_21_0_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 246`

I tried looking for what Status Code 246 means but apparently it's something made by google. I am not sure.

Here's my function code -

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.calc = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    console.log('hello');
});
```

Comment: The image most likely refers to a container which it is trying to write to a missing disk. Are you deploying your functions using `firebase deploy --only functions`?

Comment: Yes. That's what I am doing. I have just one function.

Comment: Could you share the functions code?

Comment: Yeah sure. I should have done that when writing the post. Sorry.

Comment: Your function should be returning a valid JSON response, however I doubt this is the issue here... Have you setup cloud functions properly in your firebase dashboard and have you checked your firebase credentials are pointing to the right project?

Comment: Yes I have checked everything like three times already. I can use firestore, database and authentication in the same project just fine. It's just functions that are not working. I have even tried removing node modules folders, upgrading everything to latest version. Installing node modules again. I don't even fully understand what the error message was that I got in my google cloud console.

Comment: If you haven't already, make sure you are using the latest Firebase CLI version, logout and login again. If you've done all that already try deploying to a different node version and see if the error sticks around (update the number in `"engines": { "node": "12" }` inside `package.json` - other valid versions are `10` which is stable and `14` which is in preview at time of writing).

Comment: I solved the problem by removing the function from firebase function dashboard and then redeploying.

Comment: If the issue is solved, could you provide an answer and mark it as correct?

Comment: Sure. I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something was wrong with firebase functions on google cloud sever. I just removed the faulty firebase function from functions dashboard and deployed my local function again. And it worked.